# Вылетает ошибка ConstraintViolationException при добавлении сущности в БД hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Вот мои сущности со связями OneToMany, ManyToOne

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHOR")
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "YEARS")
    private String years;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Book> books;
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "BOOK_PRICE")
    private int price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID")
    private Author author;
```

Вылетают две ошибки `ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement` и `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'author_id' cannot be null`Т.е. я не могу добавить свою книгу через форму

```
<form name="book" action="/add" method="post">
    <p>Title</p>
    <input title="Title" type="text" name="title">
    <p>Price</p>
    <input title="Price" type="text" name="price">
    <input type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>
```

если я с неё не передам author_id уже существующего автора в БД? Тогда как мне добавить новую книгу вместе с автором? Какие есть варианты решить данную проблему?

Comment: А если в сущьности есть поле Автор, то почему бы не добавить в форму поле для ввода автора и реализовать внедрение автора по имени (достав предварительно из базы) если автора нет, то либо Автор по умолчанию, либо поле в таблице нулл.

Comment: а разве правильно делать так, чтобы внешний ключ был равен null?

Comment: Судя по https://sql-language.ru/foreign-key.html: "Внешний ключ может содержать только те значения, которые фактически представлены в родительском ключе или пустые (NULL)."

Comment: Т.е. Вы предлагаете если есть автор в бд вытаскивать его по имени, а если нет, то в форме добавлять книгу с  author_id = null, а потом в другой форме добавлять автора и сетать его книге?
Можно ли как то получить стразу два объекта с формы?

Comment: Нет. Я предлагаю добавить в форму внесения книги поле "автор" и при создании книги тянуть из базы автора, сетить его в книгу и уже после этого отправлять книгу в базу. Если из формы пришло пустое значение автора сетить NULL или создать фиктивного Noname автора, которого сетить всем книгам без автора если таковые имеются. А автора надо вносить в базу раньше книг. Ведь они и в жизни сначала рождаются, а только потом пишут книги.

Comment: Как вариант, если автора нет в базе, то отрабатываете его занесение в базу вместе с созданием книги, но, по моему, проще сначала внести автора.